# How to utilize local Rotation Axis with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I have these Objects around a Circle.
I want to have every object rotate around his local Z axis by 6.6 degrees more then the previous
object:

I thought Animation Nodes is a good way of dealing with this, but there is less information than I thought.

So first things first, how do I get the Objects to rotate around the local Z - at the moment
everything is rotating globally and I dont get it to behave anyhow differently...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `offset Matrice` node with `local-axis local-pivot` option selected to rotate on object's local axis. You can get that option from `Advanced Node Settings` of the node by pressing `U` or from right panel.
[image]

We can use `Float Range` node to generate a float list with step of 6.6 for rotation.
[image]

Alternate way:
[image]
PS. Turn on degrees currently everything is in radians.